# How can I use my USB-to-MIDI keyboard to control a MIDI-in synthesizer without a PC?

Tags: midi, usb

**I Want to Use My Casio WK 200 Keyboard as a MIDI Controller**

I have a Casio WK 200 keyboard (see link below) that has USB MIDI out. I am able to use this keyboard as a controller for my DAW via that USB port without problem.

**I Want to Control Beatstep Pro with the WK 200**

I have the Beatstep Pro, which accepts traditional MIDI 5 pin DIN and also USB MIDI from a computer.

**Or, I Would Like to Directly Control a Korg Volca Synthesizer**

I have the Volca Keys, Volca Bass, and Volca Beats synthesizers, each of which accept traditional MIDI 5 pin DIN.

**I Would Love to Do So without a PC, but I'm Having Some Problems**

I would like to be able to control the Beatstep Pro and/or Volcas with my WK 200 without routing through a PC. I've tried using my Hosa USB-to-MIDI adapter cable, but that does not work (the cable does work--I can use it with MIDI out on my Roland TD-7 module to trigger Addictive Drums 2 on the PC). I **am** also able to use the WK 200 routed through the computer (via USB) routed out to the Beatstep (via USB) routed to Volcas (via MIDI) to play the Volcas, but there is an unacceptable delay; I think there are too many hoops to jump through.

I've checked (and tried various) MIDI in/out channels to eliminate the possibility that I'm just mapping things incorrectly. My hunch, and my limited understanding from research I've done online is that the Beatstep Pro cannot recognize USB MIDI from a device that isn't a computer. Same with the Volcas. It seems like I need some kind of separate device to route through if I don't want to use a PC.

**What Should I Get?**

- Kenton MIDI USB Host? (http://www.kentonuk.com/products/items/utilities/usb-host.shtml)
- I can't tell if any of the devices currently available from iConnectivity (http://www.iconnectivity.com/) would work for me or not.

Are there other devices out there? Any tricks or DIY I can consider? Or is the best bet just to spend the $100 or so on a device?

Comment: Also see [Is there a way to easily convert the USB MIDI connection on a keyboard to a conventional MIDI OUT?](https://www.midi.org/forum/is-there-a-way-to-easily-convert-the-usb-midi-connection-on-a-keyboard-to-a-conventional-midi-out)

Answer (score 1):

Most USB MIDI keyboards, synths, sequencers can only act as a USB 'device' not a USB 'host'.

I have had mixed success with using a Kenton MIDI USB host to connect USB MIDI gear to DIN MIDI gear (per the specs, it doesn't work when connecting to a USB device by a USB hub, and many USB MIDI devices actually turn out to have 'hidden' USB hubs inside them)

I have had very good success with an iConnectMIDI4+ device in 'standalone' mode - this lets you connect up to 8 USB devices (via a USB hub), as well as 4 DIN MIDI chains, and bridges them all.

Answer (score 0):

I've been looking into this myself. Have you considered a raspberry pi with a usb audio adapter?

Depending on how good you are with electronics and programming, an arduino with a custom midi shield would also do the trick.